# Console error Meteor server side

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor

I started Meteor and Angular2.
On my server side (Meteor) I have a method file where I put some methods that I call in my client.
Obviously I need some meteor library so I import them like that :

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {check, Match} from 'meteor/check';
```

The thing is, in my console output I have the messages :

server/imports/methods/methods.ts (4, 22): Cannot find module 'meteor/meteor'.
server/imports/methods/methods.ts (8, 28): Cannot find module 'meteor/check'.

The line matches with the import.
Anyone has an idea to know where is this coming from ?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a TypeScript warning, it actually does not prevent your app from working, since Meteor still loads global variables anyway as of today.

To avoid these messages, you have to provide your TypeScript compiler with proper `meteor` typings, using a version that specifies the mentioned namespaces.

E.g. get [`@types/meteor@>=1.4.0`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/meteor), and make sure to tell TypeScript to use it.

```
$ meteor npm i --save-dev @types/meteor
```

In your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": [
            "@types/meteor"
        ]
    }
}
```

Or in `*.d.ts` file:

```ts
/// <reference types="@types/meteor" />
```

Comment: Thanks again ghybs two time in a row !